# php laravel 4.2 protected rule

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make phone filed in following code to accept only numbers and limit its length by 10. 
    'phone' => 'numeric|min:10',

Above, is not working. Can anyone suggest how to make this working?

thank you

Comment: Have you read https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#available-validation-rules?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden yes, and got no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
'phone' => 'digits_between:10,99', // minimum 10 and max 99
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ''phone'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'

Comment: There was a typo, corrected now. Check that all entries of the array end in a comma `,`.

Comment: Given the syntax error, there is clearly a problem somewhere in your code. It may not be with this line. In fact, it probably isn't. You should alter your question to show a bit more of your code; then we may be able to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple :

`'phone' => 'numeric|min:10|max:99'` // minimum 10 and max 99.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 4.2 the syntax looks like that, check if it's not that kind of mistake:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
  array('phone' => 'numeric|min:10')
);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation